# Dynamically change a specific color

Tags: delphi, colors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I generate multiple shades from a given base color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655552/how-can-i-generate-multiple-shades-from-a-given-base-color)

How can change a color and make it more dark or brighter?
I am using Delphi 2007.

Comment: Check this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655552/how-can-i-generate-multiple-shades-from-a-given-base-color

Answer (score 3):

You can use a unit like this one: http://www.delphipraxis.net/157099-fast-integer-rgb-hsl.html

HSL stands for:

- Hue
- Saturation
- Luminance

So, if you change the luminance... you can get a darker or brighter color...